# I have an DBNull Exception in my If, why?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I make a program by displaying values from a database to the user. When I query whether a field is NULL, there is an error.

My attempts:

```
Dim dtContacts As New DCFLEXNorthwind.ContactsDataTable
taContacts.SelectAllByID(dtContacts, ID)
Dim r As DCFLEXNorthwind.ContactsRow = dtContacts.Rows(0)

If r.Extension Is DBNull.Value Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If r.Extension Is DBNull Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If r.Extension = DBNull.Value Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If r.Extension = DBNull Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If IsDBNull(r.Extension) Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If
```

Then the following error occurs with the valid queries:

```
The value for column extension in table Contacts is DBNull.
```

and

```
Invalid conversion from type DBNull to type String.
```

Comment: How is `r.Extension` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check if the value field even exists by comparing to `nothing`

Either use `IsNothing(r.Extension)` or `r.Extension Is Nothing`

Check for nothing first, otherwise it will error out if value does not exist.

Here is code to try

```
Dim dtContacts As New DCFLEXNorthwind.ContactsDataTable
taContacts.SelectAllByID(dtContacts, ID)
Dim r As DCFLEXNorthwind.ContactsRow = dtContacts.Rows(0)

If IsNothing(r.Extension) OR r.Extension Is DBNull.Value Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If IsNothing(r.Extension) OR r.Extension Is DBNull Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If IsNothing(r.Extension) OR r.Extension = DBNull.Value Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If IsNothing(r.Extension) OR r.Extension = DBNull Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If

If IsNothing(r.Extension) OR IsDBNull(r.Extension) Then
    txtExtension.Text = ""
Else
    txtExtension.Text = r.Extension
End If
```

Comment: As far as I know, `IsNothing` is a legacy-support function originally (in VBA) intended for checking on the value contained in a `Variant`, and I would not recommend it for new code.

Comment: I am aware but it is quicker to write for now

Comment: Yes that is it.

Answer (score 2):

How is `r.Extension` defined?

`r.Extension = DBNull.Value` might be correct, but only if it directly reads from an ADO.Net data transfer object field, like a DataReader, DataTable, or DataSet. The fields in those types use the base `Object` type, which can hold a string, datetime, numeric, etc value... anything you might get back from the database, including `DBNull`.

Your `r` variable and it's `Extension` property look more like the data transfer object was already used to populate a real type with real properties, where the `Extension` property is explicitly declared as a `string`. At this point, it's already too late to check for the database `null`, because you would not be able to assign `DBNull` to that property in the first place.

Comment: And How can I do it?

Comment: With the edit, this looks like you're using [typed DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets). Almost no one does that. But in this case, the typed dataset maps the column do a string field. I'm not sure how they handle null, but you may need to check the field in the underlying `System.Data.DataRow`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Could he check with `Nothing` instead?

Comment: Hmm... this might also be some third-party middleware, in which case you should check if the library is using [nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/), which case you might be able to say `r.Extension Is Nothing` or `String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Extension)` as in regular code. This is because `string` is already a reference type. For value types, you would check `r.Property.HasValue`

Comment: @laancelot Maybe, if whatever tool he's using is automatically mapping things to nullable types.

Comment: I often wish Nullable types had been available when ADO.Net was first written. It would have simplified a **LOT** of things.

Comment: @laancelot No that doesn't work. Why no one use the typed DataSets? What use the others?

Comment: @a.b_om People who want that kind of automation will typically choose EntityFramework or some other ORM instead. So to be clear... there's nothing wrong with them. They're just not as common.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn "For value types, you would check r.Property.HasValue" I am keeping that right in my back pocket. And thanks to OP for asking about typed DataSets.